# Does Eclipse need to build the project to do "Java Search"

Tags: java, eclipse

In Eclipse, I can click an identifier and hit Ctrl-H to do a "Java Search" for definitions or uses of that identifier (method, class, etc). However, if I disable the normal Java builder (the project uses ant), will the data become out of sync with the actual source? I know in Visual Studio it has to occasionally rebuild the intellisense data; how does this work in eclipse? Is it tied to the compiler?

Comment: AFAIK, On "SAVE" eclipse rebuilds the definitions, so it won't be out of synch irrespective which build script you use.

Comment: AFAIK no, no you don't need to build to search on the files that already exist in the project. Never had this issue myself and I deactivated the building quite a few times.

Comment: It's easy enough to try and be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have noticed that the Java editor will still underline all your wrongly typed code, even if the Java builder is disabled. This is because the JDT has 2 different internal representations of your Java code, which are independent of the java or class files (and are already updated on editing): The so called Java model and the very detailed DOM-like abstract syntax tree.

Code completion, cross references and similar things can often be **queried directly from the Java model**, that is why the menu items "References" or "Declarations" are often really fast.

You can get much more details about all that from this [EclipseCon presentation](http://www.eclipsecon.org/2005/presentations/EclipseCON2005_Tutorial29.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse compiles and builds your code automatically (by default, on every save). When you do a Java search, it searches your Java file (.java) and not the class file. This helps as the class file signature can change on every rebuild.